# AngularJs Routing, MVC6/vNext/.NET5 and MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

All the examples of using AngularJs with MVC6/vNext/.NET5 all use a static index.html file that is within the wwwroot.  Done that, but i now need to load an MVC index.cshtml page instead so i can inject settings that are in my config.json onto the page.

All i want is a default page (Home), that is loaded not matter what url is requested, provided that url is not to a js/css file or to an api controller.

I have tried adding this to my `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)` method, but now, my js and css files all pull back the Home/Index.cshtml file

```
app.UseMvc(options =>
{
    options.MapRoute("Api",
        template: "api/{version}/{controller}/{action?}",
        defaults: new { version = "v1", controller = "Page" });

    options.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

My application loads up on the default address http://localhost:port, there is no extra folder to start with.  Via angularJs, users can go to urls such as

```
http://localhost:6000/page
http://localhost:6000/page/9
http://localhost:6000/another
http://localhost:6000/another/9/sub
```

All these should load the Home/Index.cshtml page, and let angular take over routing.

I have seen an option to add something to web.config file, but i will not be using IIS so this is not an option

**EDIT**
If i update my routes to this, it seem to load the page and all js/css files, which is great.  But if i try to go directly to a angular route, nothing loads.

```
app.UseMvc(options =>
{
    options.MapRoute("Api",
        template: "api/{version}/{controller}/{action?}",
        defaults: new { version = "v1", controller = "Page" });

    options.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

**EDIT 2**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    // add automapper registrations
    app.RegisterMappingFiles();

    // Enable all static file middleware
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    // Enable Mvc for controllers
    app.UseMvc(options =>
    {
        options.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action?}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });

}
```

Comment: Are you sure all URL's should map to the home page within MVC? Maybe it would be better to only map that one controller/action. Any other URL should get redirected with an HTTP response to the correct URL to the action?

Comment: I just want users to be able to load an angular route, like /pages/9 and that will load the Home/index.cshtml page, and then angular will load the correct route on the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you have not added using Static Files in your request pipeline, therefore request against them, processed MVC routing:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(options =>
        {
            options.MapRoute("Api",
        template: "api/{version}/{controller}/{action?}",
        defaults: new { version = "v1", controller = "Page" });

            options.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });

    }
```

Your invoke app.UseStaticFiles() have to be located before invoke app.UseMvc(), that requests to static files don't reached routing middleware, since invokes middlewares perfomed in registration order.

[Documentaion on docs.asp.net](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html)

Comment: This works on initial load, but if i navigate to a client route like ```http://localhost/pages/9``` then nothing works and i get a 404 error

Comment: Have you used "{*url}" route template? I've used (in my example) wrong template ("{controller}/{action?}")

Comment: Does your invoke `app.UseStaticFiles()` located before invoke `app.UseMvc()` ? It have to be located before, that requests to static files don't reached routing middleware.

Comment: `template: "{controller}/{action?}",` - use route template `template: "{*url}",` that consume requests like  `http://localhost/pages/9` too.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!! I tried this, but i had StaticFiles after it at the time.

Comment: In addition, I had to add <base href="/" /> in <head> of my page.

Comment: Had the same issue and followed these steps. I thought my scripts were being found as chrome showed files found, but it turned out my javascript paths were wrong and the script files all just contained the index.html content.